# Saber se a aplicação foi finalizada pelo gerenciador de tarefas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Tem como o meu aplicativo saber que está sendo encerrado pelo gerenciador de tarefas?

Se o usuário for finalizar o meu aplicativo pelo gerenciador de tarefas, minha aplicação detecta essa finalização e realiza umas tarefas antes de se finalizar?

Como posso fazer isso?

Meu aplicativo fica rodando direto e é em WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não há uma forma confiável de fazer isto. O usuário sempre poderá terminar do jeito que ele quiser.

Em algumas situações é possível capturar uma mensagem do Windows e fazer alguma coisa. Mas não há garantias que esta mensagem será enviada pelo Windows. Depende de como o usuário está terminando o processo. Inclusive não precisa ser pelo gerenciador de tarefas. Tem um [artigo sobre isso do mestre Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373).

Dê uma olhada nesta documentação do [`Process.WaitForExit()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit_System_Int32_), pode te ajudar mas tenho dúvidas.

[Pergunta no SO sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9754389/221800).

Resumindo: esquece isto.

Answer (score 5):

É possível verificar através do Evento FormClosingEventArgs.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. Está funcionando na minha aplicação.

```
    private void frmLogin_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fechou pelo gerenciador de tarefas...");
        }
    }
```

Veja a documentação.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx

Comment: Isso só funciona quando o término é feito por uma forma específica. E só no WinForms, não no WPF.

Comment: Para eu não funciona, pois meu aplicativo é em wpf, e no wpf o evento é `CancelEventArgs`